# Double-clicking a .url shortcut launches the print dialog (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10

It's bothered me for a few months now, but I can't take it any more ;p
Whenever I try to open a .url shortcut (Steam games or OneDrive shortcuts to OneNote notebooks for example) a print dialog shows up. I have no idea why this is happening.
[I've created an imgur album with detailed pictures explaining the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O6Eg.jpg)

I'm using Windows 10 1709. I've been searching for a solution, but I haven't found one that helped me, so I decided to ask the people here.

Edit: [File association dump](https://pastebin.com/ixszFEMr)

Answer (score -1):

Download and apply the .URL file association registry fix (for Windows 10) via this site: [File Association Fixes for Windows 10](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/file-association-fixes-windows-10/)

Unzip the file and double-click the enclosed `.REG` file `url_fix_w10.reg`. This fixes the registry settings for InternetShortcut / .URL file type.

Comment: I tried to do it, but I got this notification:
"Cannot import C:\..\url_fix_w10.reg: Not all data was successfully written to the registry. Some keys are open by the system or other processes, or you have insufficient privileges to perform this operation."

Comment: Some keys can't be overwritten. No issues. Regardless of the error, are you able to open .URL files by double-clicking them now?

Comment: No, nothing's changed.

Comment: Pls upload the .URL file type association dump online (eg. Pastebin.com) and post the link here. Use [FileTypeDiag](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/filetypediag-dump-file-association-info/) to generate the file type asso. dump.

Comment: here: https://pastebin.com/ixszFEMr

Comment: The asso settings are fine. See if resetting the default browser via Settings > Default Apps helps.

If that doesn't help, pls run these two commands from Command Prompt (to query a registry key) and post the output here:

`reg query hkcr\clsid\{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8} /s`

and

`reg query hkcr\clsid\{06EEE834-461C-42c2-8DCF-1502B527B1F9} /s`

Comment: Same here. I have tried every reg repair and software but double-clicking on a URL shortcut only opens the print dialogue. Very frustrating!